# how to unpivot the table, from column to row

Tags: sql

I have a table like.

```
firstname   lastname   Address
 emma         olu        lagos
```

i want to convert this like...

```
firstname   emma
lastname    olu
address     lagos
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you intentionally want to denormalise your data? What have you tried, and why didn't it work? And what RDBMS are you really using (Gordon has removed the conflicting tags).

Comment: With only 3 columns three select with union would do. How you would  know that these three items are connected I don't know

Comment: is there anyway, so i can manipulate the data like this

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is "unpivoting", not pivoting.

The generic method is:

```
select 'firstname' as which, firstname
from t
union all
select 'lastname' as which, lastname
from t
union all
select 'address' as which, address
from t;
```

This assumes that the values in the columns are compatible -- meaning that they have the same type and collation.

There may be more efficient methods, depending on the database you are using.  You should provide a database tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: i  have almost 100+ rows in that table...so can not use this method.

Comment: @SandeepSingh . . . Why not?  You will just gets a result that has hundreds or thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1):

use `union all`

```
select 'firstname',firstname from tablename
union all
select 'lastname',lastnamefrom tablename
union all
select 'address',address from  tablename
```